# retrieve json data through $_POST from post request of alamofire swift3?

Tags: php, json, post, swift3, alamofire

guys, i am having problem of posting json data through alamofire 4 with swift3 and also the problem of retrieving the json data at XAMPP server side using php.
My swift 3 code did trigger the php script at XAMPP, but somehow i can't get it through $_POST variable in php
Here is my code,

```
func uploadImage(image: UIImage){
    //Now use image to create into NSData format
    let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData      
    //convert the nsdata to base64 encoded string
       let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
   // let parameters = ["image": strBase64] as Dictionary
    let parameters = ["image": strBase64]      
    print(strBase64) 
  Alamofire.request("http://localhost/Test/api/UploadPhoto.php",method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).response { response in            
    print(response)                   
                }   
}
```

Here is my server side code(the script did get triggered by the call from alamofire, but somehow i just can't get the data through calling$_POST["image"])

```
    <?php
//scripts below did get triggered, but can't get the json data through          calling $_POST["image"];
$imageString = $_POST["image"];
$filename_path = md5(time().uniqid()).".png"; 
$data = base64_decode($imageString);
file_put_contents('../AllImages/'.$filename_path, $data);
echo json_encode($_POST["image"]);
?>
```

if possible, please help me, i have been struggled for nearly a week, but can't find many clues
Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the network request in Chrome Inspector? Have you looked at a `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: i am a newbie here, but how do we inspect the console output of xampp server when it retrieves requests? and also i tried to use postman to send json data to the php script, it worked perfectly well, but when i send requests from ios side, it just can't get value from $_POST

Comment: XAMPP doesn't retrieve requests. Your browser does. You can, however, look at the apache access logs. My comment, however, was about the Chrome Inspector. Which is a piece of software in Google Chrome, a browser.

Comment: Hi Daan, Many thanks for your help, and i looked at apache's access_log, here is what i get: ::1 - - [06/Jan/2017:21:58:41 +1030] "POST /Test/api/UploadPhoto.php HTTP/1.1" 200 290 which doesn't make many sense to me

Comment: I'm sorry about my insistence on your browser usage. I assumed you were building a web application. I see you are building an iOS app now. You might be able to use `error_log(json_encode($_POST));` to see what data gets sent to your PHP script.

Comment: hmmmm, i am using chrome, but the chrome inspector isn't it is used to inspect element of the web pages? how could i use that to inspect my server's responses against requests to it?

Comment: Have a look at https://egghead.io/lessons/tools-analyze-http-requests-and-responses-with-chrome-devtools. You've been missing out if you haven't heard of the Network tab :)

Comment: thanks bro, hmmm, so you mean i use echo error_log(json_encode($POST)); and i can observe the response at my ios side?

Comment: Well, no. If you use `error_log(json_encode($_POST));` (without the `echo`) you can check your `error.log` (same dir as your `access.log` and see what your PHP script sees.

Comment: Hi, bro, i see what you mean there, but the uploadPhoto.php is the script for my ios app to access, so when i put http://localhost/Test/api/uploadphoto.php in my browser, it has no request to it and when i sent request from my ios app, the http://localhost/Test/api/uploadphoto.php webpage is not refreshed, so i can't observe the responses of my php code against my app's requests

Comment: Well, no, Chrome can only inspect the requests *it* makes (plus, any debug-linked chrome sessions on, for example, android devices). However, the `error_log` route should work for you :)

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for the new trick of using error_log, and i got an empty [ ] in the log

Comment: Well, that tells me the data isn't *really* getting sent to the server. It might be due to a too low `max_post_size` in your `php.ini`. Don't forget restarting apache after changing that.

Comment: and also i get this: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: image . (the image here is the $_POST("image"))

Comment: hmmm, i did try to send the same data which i manually copied from ios app into postman and sent from there, it works fine.

Comment: and i checked the max_post_size which is post_max_size=128M, so it should be fine. is this a problem of the json encoding at my ios side, so my php code can't recognise my image in  $imageString = $_POST["image"];?

Comment: Your `max_post_size` looks fine. The fact that your `error.log` doesn't show any data when executing the request from your app tells me that something is wrong with your app, not so much with your PHP code. Unfortunately, I can't really be of any help in that area, as I'm mainly a PHP programmer.

Comment: many thanks to you, Daan，you did help me with the php side, cos i am also trying to ask how can i inspect responses of php side when it receives requests, now i know that i can use,error_log, and you also helped me narrow down the area, i might keep trying to play around the mobile side, and see if i can get any luck, i appreciate you

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found a way to solve this problem, basically, i used urlsession.shared.datatask to help me instead of alamofire with the post request,
here is my ios side code

```
     func uploadImage(image: UIImage, completionHandler: @escaping (String) ->()){

   // Now use image to create into NSData format
            let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData

            //convert the nsdata to base64 encoded string

               let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
    // prepare json data
    let json: [String: Any] = ["image": strBase64]

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

    // create post request
    let url = URL(string: "http://10.10.10.72/Test/api/UploadPhoto.php")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // insert json data to the request
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        do {
            guard let data = data else {
                throw JSONError.NoData
            }
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
            }

             completionHandler(json["sign"] as! String)

        } catch let error as JSONError {
            print(error.rawValue)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }

        }
    task.resume()
}
```

i used dictionary to store my data, and converted it to json data format to be sent to server

```
     let json: [String: Any] = ["image": strBase64]
     let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
```

Then at the php side, i retrieved it by using

```
    $entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

, then i decoded from json which produced me an array and i can access my value by referencing image, so full php side of code as below:

```
    <?php
//get the posted json data
 $entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
//decode the json data
$decoded = json_decode($entityBody, TRUE);
$imageString = $decoded["image"];
//create a unique name for the image
 $filename_path = md5(time().uniqid()).".png"; 
//converted the image string back to image
 $data = base64_decode($imageString);
//put it on the desired location
file_put_contents('../AllImages/uploads/signature/'.$filename_path, $data);
 $response = array();
 //create the response 
 $response['sign'] = '../AllImages/uploads/signature/'.$filename_path;
 echo json_encode($response);
 ?>
```

do note here, i encode the json data again to be sent back as a response from php to my ios side, and you need to decode the response from json, so the full idea is if you encode the value to json from one side, you need to decode it from another side to access the value properly, correct me if i am wrong, i am glad that my app is up and running now with all the requests now :D